# Terminal bell without a PC speaker

Tags: command-line, sound, teminal-bell

I do not have an internal speaker in my computer.  Usually, I rely on the window manager to play a beep through my soundcard when there's a terminal bell, but since I upgraded, that is not working.

I've read that this might be because of compiz, and I tried adding the following to my `/etc/pulse/default.ca`, but it is not working:

```
load-sample-lazy x11-bell /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/drip.ogg
load-module module-x11-bell sample=x11-bell
```

Can anyone give me a hint here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it figured out.  For some reason, maybe it's Unity startup, the X11 bell is disabled by default.

Using the PulseAudio config in my question above, and the following commands issued in a terminal, it works:

```
xset b on && xset b 100
```

However, when you reboot, it'll be disabled again, so here's what I did:

1. Create a file called `/home/[youruser]/bin/bellon` and put the following text in it:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   xset b on && xset b 100
   ```
2. Type `chmod +x /home/[youruser]/bin/bellon`
3. Open the startup applications control panel
4. Click Add on the right
5. In the "name" field, put `bellon`
6. In the "command" field, put `/home/[youruser]/bin/bellon`
7. Click the add button in the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this problem persistently:

- Run `gconf-editor` and use it to change `desktop | gnome | peripherals | keyboard | bell_mode` from `off` to `on`
- Add `pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg bell.ogg` to the file `~/.xprofile`
- Add `[ "$DISPLAY" ] && xset b 100` to the file `~/.bashrc`

The simplest way to activate this solution is to reboot.

Further, to implement this solution immediately for a terminal window that is already open, run the `pactl` command and run the `xset` command in the terminal window in question.

Comment: You need the package `gnome-control-center-data` to get `glass.ogg`

Comment: No more works on Ubuntu 20.04 from July 2020 at my side.  Gnome Terminal stays mute. (AFAICS it worked with the May version)